# how to organise my abstraction?

Tags: java, abstraction

I have a set of functions that I have in a class. These function are a set of lowest commonality.

To be able to run this I need to generate certain info, but this info can arrive with my class from one of two routes.

I'll try to summarize my situation....

Lets say that I have a class as follows:

```
public class onHoliday(){

    private Object modeOfTravel;
    private Object location;

    public onHoliday(Object vehicle, Location GPScoords) {
    }
    private boolean haveFun() {
        //function to have fun, needs 4 people
    }
}
```

Lets imagine I can get to my holiday either by car or by bike.

my `haveFun()` function is dependent my type of vehicle.

But only loosely. I have another function that determines my vehicle type, and extracts the required values. for example if I send a car I may get 4 people in one go, but if I send I bike I need at least 2 to get the required 4

I have currently two options:

1. Overload my constructor, so as I can send either two bikes or a single car into it, then I can call one of 2 intermediate functions (to get the names of my 4 people for instance) before I `haveFun()` - this is what I am currently doing.
2. split the two constructors into two separate classes, and repeat my `haveFun()` in a third class, that becomes an object of my two other classes. my problem with this is that my intermediate functions are all but a few lines of code, and I don't want to have them in a separate file! (I always put classes in separate files!)

Please note, my `haveFun()` isn't something that I'm going to need outside of these 2 classes, or even being `onHoliday` (ie. there is no chance of me doing some `haveFun()` over a weekend or of an evening!).

I have though about putting `haveFun()` into an interface, but it seems a bit worthless having an interface with only a single method! Even then I would have to have the method in both of the classes -one for bike and another for car!

I have thought about having my `onHoliday` class accepting any object type, but then I don't want someone accidentally sending in a boat to my `onHoliday` class (imagine I can't swim, so its not about to happen).

It may be important to note that my `onHoliday` class is package private, and final. It in fact is only accessed via other 'private methods' in other classes, and has only private methods itself.

edit1:

I'm sure someone will suggest that I handle this in the class that send the data to the onHoliday() class. But this class (lets call it travel() ) has no reason to care about whay type of vehicle I am using, If I make it so it does care, I have simply moved the problem to another place further up the tree. and Now have to have all of my intermediate classes re-written to access either car or bike, for the moment they simply accept a vehicle object, that has a boolean switch to determine if it is a bike or a car.

edit2:

I've just had another though about having an abstract class for running my fun, then implementing it as an 'inner class' in either of my bike or car classes. Then I can access the members of my bike or class. does this make sense also?

Note: I should probably mention that I have to ensure in my onHoliday() clas that I hvae at least 4 people.

Maybe another way to think of it is...

I can get a multi page file, and extract the pages I need from a passed list of page numbers.
Or I can get a list of multiple files.

In the first case I send a single file object, and the selection of page number
in the second I send multiple files object (pre selecting the ones I am interested in).

In fact that is probably a better description

Comment: FWIW, it is absolutely not worthless to have an interface with a single method. In fact, sometimes it's a way better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample has MANY compilation problems with it, but I think I know what you're asking. If you have an abstract class `Vehicle`, you can implement `haveFun()` in the concrete classes (i.e. `Bike`, `Car`. Your Holiday class constructor can take a `Vehicle` parameter. No matter what type of vehicle it is, the implementation is outside of Holiday - rather as part of the Vehicle.

You did say it was a loose coupling though between fun and vehicle. If it doesn't make sense to implement haveFun in the Vehicle, then just have a method in Holiday that determines it - the negative to this method though is that you'll have to check for each type of Vehicle you have (i.e. `if vehicle instanceof Bike then... else if....`)

If you go with the latter, you can'd to anything in the contructor. You would want to have a method that say add's persons and Vehicles... `addPerson(Vehicle)`. Then after all have been added run isFun().

Comment: thanks for working through, I think you understood perfectly (so +1). I like your idea, but putting the information in the class one section up the tree causes me to have even more classes that repeat functionality (although I could probably get an abstract class for them to inherit from).

Answer (score 0):

I might propose a third approach: create a `Vehicle` class which handles the people-moving.

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

    public void travel(Location location) {}

    public abstract int getCapacity();

    //etc.
}

public class Bicycle extends Vehicle {

    @Override
    public int getCapacity() { return 2; }

}

public class Car extends Vehicle {

    @Override
    public int getCapacity() { return 4; }

}

final class onHoliday {

    private Vehicle vehicle;

    public onHoliday(Vehicle vehicle) {
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
        haveFun();
    }
}
```

Then, if you have any things that a `Car` and a `Bike` would do differently (but that they would both do), just put them abstract in the `Vehicle` class and override.

Comment: @gobernadro I like this idea, but I only foresee the bicycle and car classes overiding a single method. It almost seems more hassle than it is worth. Also see my edit